# Generate Dynamic SQL Query based on Filter Criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have a requirement where Client can Filter Records based on Certain Conditions.

Below is the sample Filter condition which i'm getting in Controller

```
[
   {
      "Field":"BANKNAME",
      "Operator":"=",
      "Value":"35",
      "ConditionOperator":"OR",
      "DField":"N"
   },
   {
      "Field":"BANKNAME",
      "Operator":"=",
      "Value":"15",
      "ConditionOperator":"AND",
      "DField":"N"
   },
   {
      "Field":"PTLOCATION",
      "Operator":"=",
      "Value":"261",
      "ConditionOperator":" ",
      "DField":"Y"
   ]
```

Based on Filter condition we are generating SQL Query, below is code which we have tried

```
var FilterCondition = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RptFilterCondition>>(filter);
string filterCondition = string.Empty;
var lstFilterCondition = FilterCondition.Where(a => a.DField == "N").ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < lstFilterCondition.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0 && FilterCondition.Count == 1)
    {
        filterCondition += " custom.CustomeFieldName ='" + lstFilterCondition[i].Field + "' and custom.FIELDVALUE " + lstFilterCondition[i].Operator + "'" + lstFilterCondition[i].Value + "' ";
    }
    else if (i == 0 && !isanycondition)
    {
        filterCondition += " (custom.CustomeFieldName ='" + lstFilterCondition[i].Field + "' and custom.FIELDVALUE " + lstFilterCondition[i].Operator + "'" + lstFilterCondition[i].Value + "' )" + lstFilterCondition[i].ConditionOperator;
    }
    else if (i == FilterCondition.Count - 1)
    {
        filterCondition += " (custom.CustomeFieldName='" + lstFilterCondition[i].Field + "'  and custom.FIELDVALUE " + lstFilterCondition[i].Operator + "'" + lstFilterCondition[i].Value + "' )";
    }
    else
    {
        filterCondition += " (custom.CustomeFieldName='" + lstFilterCondition[i].Field + "'  and custom.FIELDVALUE" + lstFilterCondition[i].Operator + "'" + lstFilterCondition[i].Value + "' )" + lstFilterCondition[i].ConditionOperator;
    }
}

return filterCondition;
```

Below is Filter condition generated

```
(custom.CustomeFieldName ='BANKNAME' and custom.FIELDVALUE ='35') OR 
(custom.CustomeFieldName='BANKNAME'  and custom.FIELDVALUE='15')
and (PTLOCATION = 261)
```

Below is expected output round bracket should come for same field names

```
((custom.CustomeFieldName ='BANKNAME' and custom.FIELDVALUE ='35') OR 
(custom.CustomeFieldName='BANKNAME'  and custom.FIELDVALUE='15'))
and (PTLOCATION = 261)
```

Comment: This looks like an sql injection attack waiting to happen

Comment: @00110001 can you suggest me better way to do with above logic, ill try to implement the same

Comment: `custom.CustomeFieldName` `custom.FIELDVALUE` ? So you have a table of custom fields, with each field stored as a row? Does that mean you need an `and exists(select 1 from ....)` around each test?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the code is vulnerable to the SQL injection.

One alternative is to use ORM, e.g. EF and write your own "engine" to translate from custom query model to the LINQ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/

Easier option might be to use OData, which supports user defined querying out of the box with connection to the EF - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/getting-started, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/query-options